# SSRS BIDS 2008 Solution Explorer sub folders as in report manager

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, reporting-services, bids, solution-explorer

See screen shot.
Is it possible to do any sort of organising in the solution explorer view for a large project. For example in my report manager view I am able to put all Dashboards and related reports into a folder to help organise but it seems like in solution explorer I have to have a long unorganised list. Sub folders here would be great?

[image: solution explorer view]

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[You've touched on one of my frustrations with SSRS report authoring.]

No, BIDS doesn't support the organization of reports into folders within one project.

The [mediocre] work-around is that you can have multiple SSRS projects in one solution. If you're not familiar with this, use the File Menu in BIDS, and select "Add -> New Project..." to add a separate project to your solution. The Solution Explorer you show above will add a level above the current report project with the new project above or below your existing report.

Sure seems like it would be an easy add for the product team. I haven't yet looked at SSRS 2012, to see if this is in the VS2010 environment.

Comment: it's no different with SSRS 2012 / VS2010 :(